# how to render angular directive in Highcharts tool tip in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in Angular project. We have a set of very complex tooltips to display, so was wondering if it is possible to render angular directives in Highcharts tooltips.

here is the snippet of the Highcharts code, I want to render the html from tool tip which is angular component.

```
tooltip : {
  userHTML: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return "<app-tooltip></app-tooltip>";
  }
}
```

Here the the tooltip component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.scss']
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

HTML of the component is as follows

```
<p>tooltip </p>
```

But it does not render anything. Is it possible to specify tooltips in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, such a thing is not possible right now.
More about that in this [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/243). 
You might also comment in that [thread](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7755), where this issue was first brought up.

Comment: thanks so much. I will put the comment on that thread